# Show utf-8 chars on reading csv file

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I can't display utf chars on the csv text that I show on a html table even using a php header and setting the charset on html head the characters arenot correctly shown, Do I have to set something on csv reading??

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $row = 1;
    $table  = array();
    if (($handle = fopen("csv/myfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           array_push($table, explode(';', $data[0] ) );
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <link href="./libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./libs/bootstrap/css/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./libs/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <?php
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($table[0]); $i++){
                        echo "<th>".$table[0][$i]."</th>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>

            <?php
                for($i = 1;  $i < count($table); $i++){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($j = 0; $j < count($table[$j]); $j++){
                        echo "<td>".htmlentities($table[$i][$j])."</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                } 
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="./libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP does not convert charsets. If your CSV is not in UTF-8, you have to convert it yourself...

Comment: The csv file is saved wit utf-8 encoding